# Hide/Disable firebase functions for client

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, secret-key

I am new to firebase and wondering how to disable specific functions for the client to manually put in the browsers console.

Example:

```
function createRoomDB(roomID, name, mode, start, length, aname, opcount, secrettoken) {
  firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + roomID).set({
    name: name,
    mode: mode,
    start: start,
    length: length,
    aname: aname,
    opcount: opcount,
    secrettoken: secrettoken
  });
}
```

(The names have nothing to do with my question.)

Long story short: I don't want users to simply use this command to create new data. I know that you can't hide code on front-end, but what are the easiest and most efficient ways to disable this hell of a backdoor?

I am planning to host this application on GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code can access the database, there is no way to prevent other code that runs on the same environment to also access the database.

This means you have two options:

1. Make sure all code (no matter who wrote it) only can perform authorized operations on the database.
2. Run the code in a different environment.

For the first option, you'll want to look into [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), which automatically run server-side and can enforce most requirements.

For the second option, you could for example run the code in Cloud Functions for Firebase, and call that from your API. This allows you to hide any secret values and code in a trusted environment, but does mean that you'll need to ensure [only authorized users can call that Cloud Function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions).

Comment: Have you got an example what such a secured user authorization would look like?

Comment: I added a link to a sample in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much